# Where in the CPU is the Assembly Stack located?

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, stack, x86-64

I'm studying assembly with this image:
[image: View of CPU components (compliments of UCI)]

In Assembly you'll use the stack with commands like:

```
push EAX
pop EBP
sub esp, 4
...
```

Where is this stack exactly? From the picture, the only place it could be is the `Memory`, but surely that's not the case, right? Won't that slow down the entire cycle?

Comment: Yes, it's in memory. The stack pointer itself, `esp`, is a register in the register file. The stack itself is in memory at address pointed to by `esp`. It's not very slow due to caching.

Comment: The instructions are in memory too and also affect the speed of things.

Comment: The vast majority of data is also in memory. The amount of space in the register file is tiny. Everything's in memory - instructions, stack, heap, static data, all of it. Memory access is a bottleneck for sure, but having the stack in memory doesn't slow things down any more than having the code and the rest of the data in memory does.

Comment: A round-trip to memory (store and reload) takes ~5 cycles on Intel SnB-family CPUs, thanks to [store-forwarding](http://agner.org/optimize/).  IIRC, Skylake shortened this to 4c, so it's just as short as the L1 cache load-use latency.  Agner Fog's tables unfortunately make an arbitrary decision on how to divide the latency between stores and loads, even though you can measure load latency on its own with a pointer-chasing test.  (That's how we know SnB-family L1 cache is 4c latency.)  Anyway, this is why it's preferable to do `mov ebp, eax` instead of `push eax / pop ebp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not in the CPU. The stack is, in fact, in memory. The stack pointer, however, is a register in the CPU that holds the address of the top of the stack.